# CallerMemberNameAttribute empty when using MEF?

Tags: logging, mef, .net-4.5

I was experimenting with these new .NET 4.5 attributes which promise to make logging a bit easier. The runtime should take care of providing the values, e.g. [CallerMemberNameAttribute] maps to a string parameter that should contain the method name of the caller.

However, I found that MEF seems to be interfering.

Consider the following interface:

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message, string methodName = "", string srcFilePath = "", int srcLineNumber = 0, params object[] args);
}
```

And the following implementation:

```
public sealed class Logger : ILogger
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void Write(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "", [CallerFilePath] string srcFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int srcLineNumber = 0, params object[] args)
    {
        // do some logging
    }
}
```

If you import this ILogger in an application's composition container and use the ILogger.Write method, the runtime should fill in the optional parameters marked with the [CallerX] attributes.

However, this doesn't happen, all values are set to their defaults.

Any ideas? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually discovered what was the issue: I needed to put the attributes on the interface, and not (necessarily) on the implementing class.

Adjusting the interface as shown below fixed it.

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "", [CallerFilePath] string srcFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int srcLineNumber = 0, params object[] args);
}
```